# CSS wrapping text box to multiple images

Tags: css, image, word-wrap

I have been stuck the last couple of hours trying to wrap my text box against multiple images, as seen on this picture:

[image: http://imgur.com/cJvhh]

Is it even possible without using a js library?

Also, the solution has to work in everything from IE6 to today's browsers, without js.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using float:left on two empty divs, neatly arranged like in the picture I attached, and position:relative on the text field. Works in IE6 to - success!

Answer (score 0):

The two ways I can think off would be two split the image into two and use `float:right` and `text-align` to get the text to 'follow' the image or use the multi-div hack outlined here: http://www.ideashower.com/ideas/active/css-text-wrapper/ .

But there's nothing particularly neat without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
this is a class:
    .alignLeft {
      float:left; 
      margin-right: 1em; 
  }    
    .alignRight { 
     float:right;
     margin-left: 1em;
    }


 and the image calls it:



 <img src="photo.jpg" class="alignLeft" />
```