# Fancy comment blocks CSS implementation

Tags: jquery, css, css-shapes

The goal is to accomplish this:

[image]

I already know how to crop my images, but that's really the easy part. I have a rough idea for the top (short comment) implementation regarding overlapping the image on a rounded block, adding some left padding and a negative left margin with overflow hidden and voila. However, that does work if the content expands, and since these are comment blocks, they will expand.

1) The dashed boxes represent the areas where content will be displayed. The bottom image (long comment) shows the content filling the extra space below the image, similar to how float would work. However, if this is too hard to implement, I can accept a straight rectangular shape for content and just empty space under the image.

2) The boxes are expandable both in width and height to a min-width/min-height of 150px/90px.

3) I don't care if they appear as 90 degree angles in IE because of border-radius. That's how IE displays the rest of my site using border-radius (except 9).

4) I can accept jQuery as well. Currently I'm using 1.7.2 and my site is pretty light on it so I don't mind adding some more scripts.

Comment: I think you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186618/css-wrapping-text-box-to-multiple-images) helpful.

Comment: That might be helpful for the content. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but if you hover your mouse over the down arrow, the tool tip does clearly state the 'valid' reasons for down-voting; and this question, to my mind (and remember it's entirely personal) shows no research effort.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I would ask what I'm supposed to be researching. Both answers are fairly extensive, there aren't any similar questions here on SO from my searches, and yes, I've done searches on Google for jQuery + other search terms I thought were relevant. So please, let me know what I should be researching instead because so far all you've done is scold those answering and tell me I didn't research without providing any helpful search terms of standard phrasing for this issue.

Comment: As noted, I didn't down-vote, so I can't say, really. And my comments left on the answers were to try and ensure that the site remains self-contained; answers, and questions, should have relevant code in the question, or answer, as appropriate.

Comment: @RKS And I'm the one deleting your comments, because they are not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My final version:
Demo http://dabblet.com/gist/3149345 (works in IE9+, Opera 10.5+, Chrome, FF, Safari)

HTML structure:

```
<div class="comment b">
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper"><img src=""></a>
    <div class="comment-content">
        <p><!--a lot of text here--></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

First of all, I float the `.img-wrapper` to the left, give it a white background plus top right and bottom right border radius of `50%`. And then the image over it has black background.

Then I use two pseudo-elements on the `.comment`. I give them both widths and heights equal to the `border-radius` used for `.comment` (`20px` in this case). I also give them `position: absolute` and set their `top` values to be equal to the height of `.img-wrapper` (`130px` in this case).

I give the `:before` element a white background and the `:after` element a black background. I also give the `:after` element a 100% top left `border-radius` in order to achieve the same rounded corner effect under the image wrapper as well.

```
.comment {
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.a {
    height: 90px;
}
.b:before, .b:after {
    top: 130px;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}
.b:before {
    background: #fff;
}
.b:after {
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
    background: #000;
}
.img-wrapper {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
    margin: -20px 20px 20px -20px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: This looks good too. This must be a good night to get very thorough answers this fast. Many thanks. I def don't understand how that .b:after is working since I would think that would render AFTER the .b but hey, it works exactly like I have described. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to implement it, this is the result:

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="img"><div class="inner">img</div></div>
    <p>This is the comment</p>
</div>
<div class="comment">
   <div class="img"><div class="inner">img</div></div>
   <p>Long comment. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.comment {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0;
}
.comment .img {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: -20px 20px 0 -20px;
}
.comment .img .inner {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.comment p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

​
Click here for a demo: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9wWJ6/1/)

Comment: Please post your answer here, in the answer, to guard against link-rot, and to help Stack Overflow remain useful in the event of an external site falling over. Use external sites to demo your code, not to host it.

Comment: That was fast. Do you see any potential problems doing it like this? [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wWJ6/2/) I changed a few of your styles to cut off the ghost edges of .content by taking out the overflow:auto you used to clear the float, and added a min-height instead to make sure it surrounds the .img. I did add a very unsemantic empty div to clear the float afterwards, but that was just for quick testing. I can change that later.